# Is there a way to create variables storing the values from the columns in a database without executing the same query multiple times in pymysql?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm creating a simple program in python and I want to create variables storing the values from each of the columns of my students database. I found out that I needed to execute a query each time i wanted to assign a new variable. Is there a way to create those variables without executing the same query multiple times?

```
import pymysql 
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
user='root',password='***')

conn.autocommit(True)
cur = conn.cursor()
students = [[1,'Hubert',4.0],
            [2,'Macia',3.2],
            [3,'Pontas',3.5],
            [4,'Bartek',4.0],
            [5,'Dundersztyc',2.1],
            [6,'Diabel',2.7],
            [7,'Kondzias',3.1],
            [8,'Krapol',3.4],
            [9,'Any',2.8],
            [10,'Jacenty',2.5]]
try:
    use = 'USE students'
    cur.execute(use)
    for identi,name,gpa in students:
        query1 = 'INSERT INTO students (id,st_names,gpa) VALUES 
                                                     (%s,%s,%s)'
        cur.execute(query1,(identi,name,gpa))
    query = 'SELECT * FROM students'

    cur.execute(query)
    ids = [ide['id'] for ide in cur]

    cur.execute(query)
    names = [name['st_names'] for name in cur]

    cur.execute(query)
    gpas = [gpa['GPA'] for gpa in cur]

finally:
    conn.close()
```

When I printed ids, names, gpas when I executed the query only once I got the first list of ids. The names and gpas were empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this expression ...

```
ids = [ide['id'] for ide in cur]
```

... you iterate over the cursor, which exhausts the iterator. The next time you iterate over it, there's simply nothing left to loop over, hence the list comp returns an empty list.
Executing the query again creates a fresh iterator, but you'd have to do that for each field you'd want to retrieve.

Every [DB API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) compliant cursor offers methods to [fetch](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#fetchone) the result (or parts thereof) of an SQL statement that has been executed the in the cursor.

Since `PyMySQL` is DB API compliant, these [methods](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.fetchall) are available to you. In your case, you'll probably want to go for ...

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM students'
cur.execute(query)
result = cur.fetchall()
```

... to retrieve a list of dicts representing the full result set.

```
# [{'id': 1, 'st_names': 'Hubert', 'GPA': 4.0}, {'id': 2, 'st_names': 'Macia', 'GPA': 3.2}, ...]
```

As an aside, [`executemany()`](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/cursors.html#pymysql.cursors.Cursor.executemany) lets you do bulk inserts without the need to manually loop over your sequence of query parameters:

```
query1 = 'INSERT INTO students (id,st_names,gpa) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)'
cur.executemany(query1, students)
```